# Gamemaker collisions

Tags: collision, gml

i'm making a 1v1 tank game and i'm going crazy with collision
this is the code of the tank

```
if keyboard_check(vk_right){   
    obj_canon.image_angle -= 1.33
 }
  if keyboard_check(vk_left){   
    obj_canon.image_angle += 1.33
 }
// Si canshoot es verdadero y no estamos en tiempo de espera


if keyboard_check(ord("W")) {
 motion_add(image_angle+90,_velocidad)

}
if keyboard_check(ord("A")) {
   image_angle +=1.33 ;

}
if keyboard_check(ord("D")) {
     image_angle -=1.33;
      
}
if keyboard_check(ord("S")) {
      motion_add(image_angle-90,_velocidad)
}
```

if anyone have any suggestion i'll be pleased to take it

I searched many tutorials but none have the movement like mine so no one will do the work

Comment: What is your question here?